# Init filter of tableParams with a compound name issue

Tags: angularjs, filter, ngtable

When I init a table with ng-init like this:

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" template-pagination="custom/pager" template-header="custom/header" ng-init="tableParams.filter({name:'George Harrison'})" show-filter="true" class="table">
```

And this word is at the table. The table not show any item. But when I type only the word 'George'(none white space), the items appear.

How I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you define `tableParams`, you can set the [initial `filter` value](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/4):

```
$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
    page: 1,            
    count: 10,          
    filter: {
        name: 'George Harrison'       // initial filter
    }
}, {
...
```

However, if you must use `ng-init`, the correct syntax would be:

```
ng-init="tableParams.filter()['name'] = 'George Harrison'"
```

**Update:**

If you would like to try this code, [here is a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rGavm0kD9xgsWZWhEzsI?p=preview).

Comment: Ok, this really works. But, this just inserts on text field of column filter that string and starts the table with this filter setted. But the problem still continues. If the string is compound, the filter shows nothing.

Comment: I didn't experience that when I tested this.  I will update my answer with a plunker demonstrating that this works in a vacuum.